# Unable to execute rosrun after roscore command

Tags: rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS indigo on ubuntu 14.04. Please find below shell output. I am following "Learning ROS for robotics programming" by Aaron Martinez.

rahul@rahul-Inspiron-N5110:~$ cd /home/rahul/dev/rosbook/
rahul@rahul-Inspiron-N5110:~/dev/rosbook$ roscreate-pkg chapter2_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
/home/rahul/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials already exists, aborting
rahul@rahul-Inspiron-N5110:~/dev/rosbook$ rosmake chapter2_tutorials
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['chapter2_tutorials']                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/rahul/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20170521-122436
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['chapter2_tutorials'] to:
['chapter2_tutorials']     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkinive 0/25 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cmake_modules [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cmake_modules ROS_NOBUILD in package cmake_modules
 No Makefile in package cmake_modules
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                            
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> chapter2_tutorials [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< chapter2_tutorials [PASS] [ 7.51 seconds ]             
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 25 packages with 0 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/rahul/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20170521-122436             
rahul@rahul-Inspiron-N5110:~/dev/rosbook$ roscore
... logging to /home/rahul/.ros/log/e071277c-3df2-11e7-a120-ccaf7805625b/roslaunch-rahul-Inspiron-N5110-5811.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://rahul-Inspiron-N5110:36078/
ros_comm version 1.11.21

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosdistro: indigo
- /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5823]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://rahul-Inspiron-N5110:11311/

setting /run_id to e071277c-3df2-11e7-a120-ccaf7805625b
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5836]
started core service [/rosout]
rosnode
rosnode list

rosnode info
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
rosnode info rosout

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262197/unable-to-execute-rosrun-after-roscore-command/) by [rahulsharma333369](https://answers.ros.org/users/30476/rahulsharma333369/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-21**:
I don't really follow how the output you included shows that `rosrun` doesn't work (I only see `roslaunch` output), but in any case: *don't use `rosmake` on Indigo*. It's unfortunate, but that book (1st ed anyway) is from 2013, which is 'ages' ago.

**Comment by [rahulsharma333369](https://answers.ros.org/users/30476/rahulsharma333369/) on 2017-05-21**:
rosrun doesn't work means after "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node" command, new window is expected which will have turtle. Also rosnode info, rostopic list command doesn't return anytthing.
What book would you recommend for learning ROS. I am new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you typing all these commands in the same terminal as where you started `roscore`?

If so, then that is your problem: `roscore` should run in its own terminal. If it works correctly, `roscore` is not supposed to 'end' and give you your terminal back. Use `ctrl+c` to stop it when you are done with it.

Open (a) new terminal(s) for the other command(s).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rahulsharma333369](https://answers.ros.org/users/30476/rahulsharma333369/) on 2017-05-22**:
Hey thanks. Yes, I was trying in the same terminal. My bad, was referring old book by Arron.